# cannot access com.amazonaws.protocol.StructuredPojo

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-events

I am trying to use `aws-java-sdk-events` in my project to dynamically create cloudwatch events to trigger lambda. The following snippet of code produces `cannot access com.amazonaws.protocol.StructuredPojo` on project compilation:

```
Target target = new Target()
      .withArn("")
      .withId("");
```

Also, Intellij Idea highlights it with the same message. As far as I understood, the problem is with `@SdkProtectedApi` that prohibits to do any operations on the class. I don't quite understand what would be the way to set targets then. Any possible help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you dynamically trying to create new rules / targets? CloudWatch Events (now EventBridge) is eventually consistent with new rules & targets. So new rules / targets need few minutes to take effect.